# Adding functions to makemigration in Django (Elasticsearch Index)

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-models, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-py

I am trying to create a project that combines Django and Elasticsearch. What I want to do is create or update an Elasticsearch Index when a Django migrations file is created.

The brute way would be to detect any changes in the migrations folder and execute a function that will create/update the Elasticsearch Index accordingly, but I want to create something that will directly respond to the makemigrations command, as that is more intuitive.

Looking at the migrations doc in Django, I can't really find useful information on how the migrations file is created.

Thank you for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an empty migration file (passing `--empty` to `makemigrations`) and then add the code to update the elasticsearch index manually. The migration gframework will then take care of the execution...